# .map returning first value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, array-map

world... again.

I'm stumped by something that should be straightforward, but right now I cant see it. I'm trying to map over a simple array and display values. Each card should have a button that opens a bs modal which should show more information on the particular array object. but instead it returns infomation only on the first object in the array.

I think there's a concept here that I'm not getting and it's a shade embarassing. Thaank's in advance for your help.

```
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const modalInfo = [
    { name: "james", number: "1" },
    { name: "Jackie", number: "2" },
    { name: "Ariane", number: "3" },
    { name: "Mike", number: "4" }
  ];
  return (
    <>
      <div className="App">
        {modalInfo.map((info) => (
          <div className="card">
            <h1>{info.name}</h1>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-primary"
              data-bs-toggle="modal"
              data-bs-target="#staticBackdrop"
            >
              Show more
            </button>

            <div
              class="modal fade"
              id="staticBackdrop"
              data-bs-backdrop="static"
              data-bs-keyboard="false"
              tabindex="-1"
              aria-labelledby="staticBackdropLabel"
              aria-hidden="true"
            >
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="staticBackdropLabel">
                      #{info.number}
                    </h5>
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="btn-close"
                      data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                      aria-label="Close"
                    ></button>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">{info.name}</div>
                  <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button
                      type="button"
                      class="btn btn-secondary"
                      data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                    >
                      Close
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">
                      Understood
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        ))}
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

This is the current error in console , I copied the code from sandbox and plugged it into another project with bootstrap:

> Uncaught TypeError: 'querySelector' called on an object that does not
> implement interface Element. findOne selector-engine.js:24
> _showElement modal.js:217 show modal.js:143 y index.js:251 show backdrop.js:54 y index.js:251 r index.js:273 selector-engine.js:24:43

Comment: Any errors in the console? I suspect the script breaks after the first iteration. Also, you are generating multiple `id="staticBackdrop"`, you can't do that. An ID must be unique.

Comment: This is the current error in console , I copied the code from sandbox and plugged it into another project with bootstrap: 
Uncaught TypeError: 'querySelector' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.
    findOne selector-engine.js:24
    _showElement modal.js:217
    show modal.js:143
    y index.js:251
    show backdrop.js:54
    y index.js:251
    r index.js:273
selector-engine.js:24:43

Comment: I strongly suggest you move away from the regular, jQuery-based Bootstrap and use something React specific like https://react-bootstrap.github.io/

Answer (score 0):

`id` attributes must be unique in a document. You are re-using `staticBackdrop` in each *map* iteration so they're being duplicated.

When Bootstrap tries to grab the modal target by `#staticBackdrop`, it only gets the first one because that's what happens with repeated IDs.

Using the `info.id` properties from your sandbox link, try incorporating that into the `id` and `data-bs-target` attributes

```jsx
{modalInfo.map((info) => (
  <div className="card" key={info.id}> {/* keys are important, don't use index */}
    <h1>{info.name}</h1>
    <button
      type="button"
      className="btn btn-primary"
      data-bs-toggle="modal"
      data-bs-target={`#staticBackdrop_${info.id}`}
    >
      Show more
    </button>

    <div
      className="modal fade"
      id={`staticBackdrop_${info.id}`}
      data-bs-backdrop="static"
      data-bs-keyboard="false"
      tabIndex="-1"
      aria-labelledby={`staticBackdropLabel_${info.id}`}
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      {/* the rest of your markup goes here */}
    </div>
  </div>
))}
```

You also have a bunch of `class` attributes that should be `className` and a repeated `id="staticBackdropLabel"` that should get a similar treatment to `staticBackdrop`.

[image: Edit Conway v BootstrapModal (forked)]

Comment: I can see what you're getting at but bootstrap has an issue with the template literals: https://codesandbox.io/s/conway-v-bootstrapmodal-edqc6f?file=/src/App.js

Comment: @ire.Ulysses you weren't meant to literally put `{/* etc */}`. Also, you have a bunch of `class` attributes that should be `className` and another repeated `id="staticBackdropLabel"`

Comment: Thank you so much for your help with this. Yesterday I went down the rabbit hole of trying every combination to combat this where I should've probably started over or given myself a break to think. Story of my programming life tbh, glad this one only cost me a day.

Answer (score 0):

You must be getting some unique key error in your console.
Give a `key` to you card that acts a a unique `id` for your card.

```
<....
   {modalInfo.map((info, index) => (
     <div className="card" key={info.index}>  
...>
```

You can give `index` as well as a `unique id` but that not correct way just for testing you can. But from what I see is the `number` property is incrementing by 1 as well so that's why I have kept `index` as the `key`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this hasn't helped. the main issue now I think as pointed out by another commenter is the fact that the data-bs-target id wasn't unique. I've tried adding some tweaks to the code also the id recommendation and it's not helped.

Comment: is the code sandbox link proper? DO you get the same undefined classList error on local machine as well?

Comment: Local machine errors as follow:Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique 
Uncaught TypeError: 'querySelector' called on an object that does not implement interface Element.
    findOne selector-engine.js:24
    _showElement modal.js:217
    show modal.js:143
    y index.js:251
    show backdrop.js:54
    y index.js:251
    r index.js:273
selector-engine.js:24:43